# Change Pandas crosstab contingency table in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have generated a pandas crosstab table from two columns (named: `V1` and `new`) in another data frame. Now I would like to leave the `V1` as it is, but I would like to change the name of `0.0` to `A` and the name of `2.0` to `B`.
In the next step I would like double (x2) each value in `A` and add the values of `1.0` for each row. The same should be done for column `B`. So double the values in column `B` and adding the values from column `1.0`. Then I would like to delete the column `1.0`.

Input:

```
   new       0.0      1.0      2.0
V1          
0             40      10        1
1            340      139       10


   new       A      B
V1          
0           90     12
1           819    159
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df = df.rename({'0.0': 'A', '2.0': 'B'}, axis=1)

df['A'] = df['A'] * 2 + df['1.0']
df['B'] = df['B'] * 2 + df['1.0']

df = df.drop('1.0', axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

new    A    B
V1           
0     90   12
1    819  159
```